# Series of application freezes and battery discharging fast after turning on flash in camera once

Tags: applications, battery, music-player, lg, system-freeze

I have LG Optimus L9 P760, Swift L9 with Android system.

Few days ago I was using my phone camera and turned on "flash" under settings for it (the lamp). When I wanted to take a photo, camera application frozen. I restarted the phone (the lamp is not lighting). I cannot take any photo or video now, application freezes each time I try to run it (I only see the welcome screen).

From that day I experience also:

1. The standard music player - it starts, shows the title bar and freezes before displaying the songs list (the media explorer shows all the music files).
2. Battery discharges extremely fast - the phone does not last for even 8 hours on stand by (when I don't use it). And before that day I could use it for 2-3 days without charging.

Both that changes were rapid (before that the battery was working very well for several months).

Phone reset didn't help. Same for putting the battery off and on.

**Can it be something related to Android/software?** Or is it a hardware problem?

Can I somehow reset the camera/music player (even if I haven't made changes to music player)?